# what is mean by xnlp in this below url?

Tags: heremaps, here-maps-rest

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.42.1&apikey=GvKBBnxhOzJrcWIBBPt-6fS8s0GiAp_IhsYykVg343U&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo%21-33.86973%2C151.20825&waypoint1=geo%21-37.81738%2C144.96754&representation=display

i want the detail explaination of xnlp means, full form and its use in here map. need to know the explaination of the value of xnlp also, need to know explaination of all the param and which param is required to process all the request.